# HTML Textarea does not keep its content (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

A html text area is binded to a popup screen.

[image: textarea]

Texts dont remain in the area after the popup is re-opened. Save button saves the content of textarea to a variable:

```
let textAreaContent=""; //in the beginning of script page.

function handleClick(){
    textAreaContent = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    console.log(textAreaContent)
    return null;
}
```

I can see the changed value of textarea content in console when i click on save button. I tried to assing textAreaContent variable to HTML textarea but it didnt work. Popup page:

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="40" style="border 1px solid black">${textAreaContent}</textarea>
<button onClick={handleClick()}>Save</button>
```

Why the content of textarea does not change? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check the scope of textAreaContent. It has to min live in parent scope (not ideal in global scope) not only in your popup scope.

Answer (score 1):

First you made a typo in with the style attribute, Here is the correct syntax.

```
style="border: 1px solid black;"
```

For the onClick handler try the following instead :

```
<button onClick="handleClick()">Save</button>
```

If you want the information to persist you can use a global variable or session storage.

```
  function handleClick() {
    var textAreaContent = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("textAreaContent", textAreaContent);
    return null;
  }
```

You can then get the information later with the sessionStorage.getItem method later and add the value back

```
// whenever popup opens, 
document.getElementById("textarea").value = sessionStorage.getItem('textAreaContent')
```

Comment: textAreaContect is already global but sessionStorage works here. Thanks.